# Onchange Selectbox and php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using a selectbox with `onchange = "this.form.submit()"` and a table with php that shows data according to the selection, well, it works fine, but when I select an option and the page refresh, selectbox always shows as value the first element. I want that it shows the element that I've selected. This is the code

```
<form action="#" >
<select name="proyect" id="proyect" onchange = "this.form.submit()">
<?php
$SQL = "SELECT id  FROM categories ORDER BY nomCategories ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"><?php echo $row["nomCategories"];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: your question is not bad, but you didn't provided any code? how people can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You should do same as `viewstate` in `ASP.NET`. For this you should send the selected index to the server. There is some ways like:
Create a `<input type='hidden' ... />` and set the selected index to property `value` of this hidden input (Note that this element must be created into the `form` element)
At this stage you can retrieve the index by `$_GET` or `$_POST`
And while the page is rendering you can set this index to the `select box`

**UPDATE(detailed)**
Change your HTML&PHP code to this:

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" name="pindex" value="" />
    <select name="proyect" id="proyect" onchange = "mysubmit(this.parentNode)">
    <?php
    $SQL = "SELECT id  FROM categories ORDER BY nomCategories ASC";
                $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"><?php echo $row["nomCategories"];?> </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>

<script type='javascript'>
    document.getElementById("proyect").selectedIndex = 
    <?php
    if( isset( $_POST['pindex']))
        echo $_POST['pindex'];
    else
        echo '0';
    ?>

    function mysubmit(form)
    {
        document.getElementsByName("pindex")[0].value = document.getElementById("proyect").selectedIndex ;
        form.submit()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @user2553299: In the first time page load the PHP echos `0`, But when an user select an item in select box, the PHP echos `$_POST['pindex']`